# Gmail file attachment download is failing with getContentResolver()

Tags: android, gmail

I'm writing a process that downloads/ copies a file attached to Gmail on to the SD card that my application can then read.
When a user clicks on the attachment my activity is fired and I use the following code to save to local storage;

```
InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream( intent.getData() );
String ext = intent.getType().equals("text/xml") ? ".xml" : ".gpkg";
localFile = new File( TILE_DIRECTORY, "tmp/"+intent.getDataString().hashCode()+ext);

// If we haven't already cached the file, go get it..
if (!localFile.exists()) {
    localFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    FileIO.streamCopy(in, new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile)) );
}
```

The FileIO.streamCopy is simply;

```
public static void streamCopy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException{
    byte[] b = new byte[BUFFER];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(b)) != -1) {
            out.write(b, 0, read);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
}
```

This all works fine on a small file, but with a 6Mb attachment only 12Kb is ever getting written. I'm not even getting an error, the process just runs through very quickly and i'm left with a corrupt file.

This process is run in its own thread and is part of a larger app with a lot of fileIO, so there is no issue with permissions/ directories etc.

Is there something different I should be doing with the stream?

Incidentally, intent.getData() is

```
content://gmail-ls/mexxx@gmail.com/messages/6847/attachments/0.1/BEST/false
```

and intent.getType() is

```
application/octet-stream
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All work's fine with this code

```
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData()) );

File dir = getExternalCacheDir();
File file = new File(dir, Utils.md5(uri.getPath()));

OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(file) );

streamCopy(in, out);
```